# Restful Service is taking too much time after some calls

Tags: c#, rest

When I call a restful service, it is working fine for some times, and after that I am not getting any response from the service. Again when I do a IIS reset, it's working for some time and the same problem occurs again. I do know where the problem is exactly. I have listed the contract below (I am trying to get the status of window and web services in my solution).

Can someone help me in this? Thanks in advance.

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
List<Entities.ServiceCollection> GetServiceStatus();
```

Comment: Is the service outputting any logs? Can you debug the webservice?

Comment: "I do know where the problem is exactly." I suspect this to be untrue! Also, the error is unlikely to be caused by the way you call the service, and more likely to do with the service itself. The contract probably won't be enough to diagnose the problem - you need to debug the service.

Comment: When i debug the service it is giving me the right jason output.The problem is when i call using a client many times.